# Value from other Vue component

Tags: vue.js

How can I get the value of an element in another Vue component and use it in another Component. For example I want to get the value of a textbox from a separate component and use it another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using event bus to communicate between any components,

Component A:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentA',
  methods: {
    onTextAreaChange: function(event) {
      this.$root.$emit('changed', event)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Component B:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('changed', (data) => {
      //...console data here
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can the mounted function also handle multiple methods or just a single one?

Comment: Yes, it can. Eg. you can initialize your model values in mounted or maybe for some xhr request.

Comment: May I ask what is the event, do I need to add the function to the textbox

Comment: Yes. <textarea @change="onTextAreaChange"></textarea>

Comment: hi i hope you answer this follow up question, what if a <a> tag is clicked how can I use the same function

Comment: <a href="javascript:void 0" @click="onTextAreaChange" />

Comment: Another question, sorry to bother but how can I bind the exported data into component b